# Get all collection records related to a model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

```
// Note model 
attributes: {
        // Relations
        notebook: {
            model: 'Notebook'
        },
}
```

and

```
// Notebook
attributes: {
        // Relations
        owner: {
            model: 'User'
        },

        notes: {
            collection: 'Note',
            via: 'notebook'
        }
}
```

in the controller:

```
        Notebook.findOne({owner: user.id}, function (err, notebook) {
            if (err || !notebook) {
                return res.serverError(err);
            }
// --> until here it goes all fine, finding the Notebook
            Note.find().where({notebook: notebook.id}, function (err, notes) {
                if (err || !notes) {
                    return res.serverError(err);
                }

                return res.json({notebook: notebook, notes: notes});
            })
        })
```

It is clear that I am trying to get all Notes related to the Notebook. When debugging, I get until the `Note.find()` and then I don't even enter the callback, so I don't get any results for `Note`. The `err` is null, so I wouldn't know if something's wrong.

I am betting that I have set up my model relations wrongly, but it seems correct to me, as from what I have read in tutorials.

P.S. I do have the records in the database, and the ER relations there are setup correctly, because inserting `Note` records works without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models relations seems to be fine.

I think the error come from the fact that there is no callback param in the [`where` method](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/queries/where.html).

Try this instead:

```
Note
  .find()
  .where({ notebook: notebook.id })
  .exec(function (err, notes) {
    ...
});
```